# GitHub Actions: How to get contents of VERSION file into environment variable?

Tags: docker, github-actions

In my Docker project's repo, I have a VERSION file that contains nothing more than the version number.

```
1.2.3
```

In Travis, I'm able to `cat` the file to an environment variable, and use that to tag my build before pushing to Docker Hub.

```
---
env:
  global:
    - USER=username
    - REPO=my_great_project
    - VERSION=$(cat VERSION)
```

What is the equivalent of that in GitHub Actions? I tried this, but it's not working.

```
name: Test

on:
  ...
  ...

env:
  USER: username
  REPO: my_great_project

jobs:
  build_ubuntu:
    name: Build Ubuntu

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BASE: ubuntu

    steps:
    - name: Check out the codebase
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build the image
      run: |
        VERSION=$(cat VERSION)
        docker build --file ${BASE}/Dockerfile --tag ${USER}/${REPO}:${VERSION} .

  build_alpine:
    name: Build Alpine

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BASE: alpine

    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I've also tried this, which doesn't work.

```
- name: Build the image
  run: |
    echo "VERSION=$(cat ./VERSION)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    docker build --file ${BASE}/Dockerfile --tag ${USER}/${REPO}:${VERSION} .
```

Comment: Do you need `VERSION` in the environment, or do you just need it as the value of the `VERSION` variable in the `docker build` command?

Comment: I just need it to use `docker build`, `docker tag`, and `docker push`

Comment: If you don't need in in your environment, you could use `VERSION=$(< VERSION)` and then just use `$VERSION` in the same `run` step. What you did in your first attempt, basically. How is that not working?

Comment: Ugh, I'm an idiot. It was a different step that was failing when I was running what I had.

Comment: It seems I do need `VERSION` in the environment. I'm trying to use it in multiple steps, and don't want to set it every time. Is there a way to add it for all steps?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I went down the road that [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) was talking about with having `VERSION` in my environment vs just in that specific step.

This worked for me to set the variable in one step, then use it in separate steps.

```
- name: Set variables
  run: |
    VER=$(cat VERSION)
    echo "VERSION=$VER" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Build Docker Image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    file: ${{ env.BASE_DIR }}/Dockerfile
    load: true
    tags: |
      ${{ env.USER }}/${{ env.REPO }}:${{ env.VERSION }}
      ${{ env.USER }}/${{ env.REPO }}:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

As I want to re-use ENV_VAR between jobs, this is how I do it. I wish I could find a way to minimize this code.

In this example, I use VARs from my Dockerfile. But it will work from any file.

```
  pre_build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
        ...
      -
        name: Save variables to disk
        run: |
          cat $(echo ${{ env.DOCKERFILE }}) | grep DOCKERHUB_USER= | head -n 1 | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g' > ~/varz/DOCKERHUB_USER
          cat $(echo ${{ env.DOCKERFILE }}) | grep GITHUB_ORG= | head -n 1 | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g' > ~/varz/GITHUB_ORG
          cat $(echo ${{ env.DOCKERFILE }}) | grep GITHUB_REGISTRY= | head -n 1 | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g' > ~/varz/GITHUB_REGISTRY
          echo "$(cat ~/varz/DOCKERHUB_USER)/$(cat ~/varz/APP_NAME)" > ~/varz/DKR_PREFIX
      - 
        name: Set ALL variables for this job | à la sauce GitHub Actions
        run: |
          echo "VERSION_HASH_DATE=$(cat ~/varz/VERSION_HASH_DATE)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "VERSION_HASH_ONLY=$(cat ~/varz/VERSION_HASH_ONLY)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "VERSION_CI=$(cat ~/varz/VERSION_CI)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "VERSION_BRANCH=$(cat ~/varz/VERSION_BRANCH)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      -
        name: Show variables
        run: |
          echo "${{ env.VERSION_HASH_DATE }} < VERSION_HASH_DATE"
          echo "${{ env.VERSION_HASH_ONLY }} < VERSION_HASH_ONLY"
          echo "${{ env.VERSION_CI }} < VERSION_CI"
          echo "${{ env.VERSION_BRANCH }} < VERSION_BRANCH"
      - 
        name: Upload variables as artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: variables_on_disk
          path: ~/varz

  test_build:
    needs: [pre_build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
       ...
      - 
        name: Job preparation | Download variables from artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: variables_on_disk
          path: ~/varz
      - 
        name: Job preparation | Set variables for this job | à la sauce GitHub Actions
        run: |
          echo "VERSION_HASH_DATE=$(cat ~/varz/VERSION_HASH_DATE)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "VERSION_HASH_ONLY=$(cat ~/varz/VERSION_HASH_ONLY)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "VERSION_BRANCH=$(cat ~/varz/VERSION_BRANCH)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "BRANCH_NAME=$(cat ~/varz/BRANCH_NAME)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```