# How to run a Github Action Task if merging to master or the VERSION file contains letter b

Tags: github-actions

I would like to publish a Python package to pypi if merging to master `OR` a file named `VERSION` contains letter `b`. The `VERSION` file is located in the root of this repo.

I'm able to get the "merging to master" part work with the following code.

```
publish:
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: [self-hosted, generic-linux]
    container: python:3
    steps:
      - name: Download artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: package
          path: ./dist

      - name: Install requirements
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install --upgrade --prefer-binary twine

      - name: Upload to artifactory
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
        env:
          TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-all
          TWINE_REPOSITORY: pypi-all
          TWINE_USERNAME: "${{ secrets.PUBLISH_USERNAME }}"
          TWINE_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.PUBLISH_BEARER_TOKEN }}"
        run: |
          twine upload --skip-existing --verbose dist/*
```

However, I'm not sure how to add an `OR` condition to check the content of a file. Could someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Checking the file and adding a condition for it is doable but when would it be triggered? Is that VERSION file pushed from some other repo to this repo? How would this be triggered to check this file? On which event exactly?

Comment: My intention is to allow people to publish any beta version (e.g. 0.0.1b1) packages even when they are on a feature branch. However, if they want to publish a non-beta version (e.g. 0.0.2) package, it must happen when the branch is merged to master.

Comment: Right. If that's the case then it becomes a bit more involved. Instead of just checking for only `b`, the proper version string should be matched and compared. For example, with only `b`, these arbitrary version strings e.g. `b`, `beta`, `abc`, etc. would be valid. If that's not an issue then it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add an extra step to read the content (manually or using some existing GH action like https://github.com/marketplace/actions/read-files-action) of the file and add a condition the the Upload step, to check if the file contains the required string (with https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains), like:

```
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Read Version
        id: version
        uses: komorebitech/read-files-action@v1.5
        with:
          files: '["VERSION"]'
      - name: Echo Version
        run: echo "${{ steps.version.outputs.content }}"


      - name: Upload to artifactory
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' || contains(steps.version.outputs.content, 'b')}}
```

Remember to checkout the code of the repo before try to read the file

Comment: Here is another way to read a file into a variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721253/github-actions-how-to-get-contents-of-version-file-into-environment-variable